# Generation of pdf in multiple threads - ExpertPdf Pdf Library for .NET

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, parallel-processing, task

I thank you in advance for your support.

I am improving a process of generating a pdf file.

The process currently is sequential and takes a long time to generate

The ephtmltopdf library is used with a method that calls an .aspx page and returns an array of bytes to the client.

To improve the times, the functionality was changed to be through threads, task, parallelFor, but if I succeed.

It should be noted that the current process takes less than or equal to one second to respond.

This development is on a web service .asmx and also on wcf in C#.

Any suggestions why the parallel execution doesn't succeed?

I attach an example graph:

The web service calls at runtime
an .aspx page that are in the same directory
of the project(image). This page in the PageLoad event has some logic for accessing DB(1 record) and querying html templates with a tag that will be replaced.
[image]

```
int batchSize = 3;
int NumRegistro = request.Count;

var numberOfBatches = Math.Ceiling((decimal)(NumRegistro / batchSize));
for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfBatches - 1; i++)
{
    var result = request.ToList().Skip(i * batchSize).Take(batchSize);
               
    foreach (var row in result)
    {
        Task<Response> taskPdf = Task.Run(() => ConvertHtmlToPdf(row.Request));
        tasks.Add(taskPdf);
    }

    Response[] results = await  Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
               
}


private  Response ConvertHtmlToPdf(object request)
{
    Response objResponse = new Response();
          
    string uri = "http://localhost:8080/" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["websiteWcfiis"] + "PAGINAS/page.aspx?ci=" +request.param1;
            
    byte[] bytes = PdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromUrl(uri); //--> calls the .aspx page that has the log replacement tag

    Response.parambytes = bytes ;

    return Response;
}
```

When it is executed in parallel, it does not have the expected results, it takes more time to respond.

The objective is to execute it in parallel so that the times decrease, since there are 230,000 records to process

Comment: I am confused: _"It should be noted that the current process takes less than or equal to one second to respond."_ - Overall or per 1 of those 230,000 records? Before you threw yourself into parallelization hell, did you measure where your bottlenecks were? I would guess, you are flooding your local WebService, now. CPU and MEM probably are or the higher end of the scale?

Comment: It takes 1 second to register. What is sought is that several records are executed at the same time to minimize time.

Correct, the service is being tested locally and on the server.

 We modified the web service to execute several tasks, but I suspect that the .aspx page that invokes the service is causing the bottleneck or the library that converts to pdf

At the infrastructure level I have these data 8-core CPU and 32 GB memory

Comment: Ok, so what I am _suspecting_ is that you are now basically committing a denial of service attack on yourself. Try to drastically reduce parallelization. Maybe start with 2 then go up until you see no more improvement. That's the sweet spot. If you see degradation, go back again. Then look for another way to speed up things.

Comment: Not sure if at 230k it already matters, but maybe try and benchmark some little things, too. Like the building of the url. I am pretty sure that can be improved to be lighter on GC pressure and runtime.

Comment: If you have file system i/o then that probably also has potential to be optimized.

Comment: **Denial of service attack against yourself, that's right.**
We already adjusted that in the IIS, but still do not have the expected results.


We start with 2 and then we go up but we find ourselves in the same thing.. we continue looking for what could be causing the blockage.

Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: **system i/o then that probably also has potential to be optimized**  we apply the singleton pattern in order to maintain and read them in memory.

Comment: Please note you have a bug. With `var numberOfBatches = Math.Ceiling((decimal)(NumRegistro / batchSize));` you are dropping records. For example, if `NumRegistro` were `5` and `batchSize` is `3` then `numberOfBatches` is `1` as you are doing the integer maths before the cast. What you need is `Math.Ceiling((decimal)NumRegistro / batchSize)`. Or, even better, avoid casting: `int numberOfBatches = NumRegistro / batchSize + (NumRegistro % batchSize == 0 ? 0 : 1);`.

Comment: Keep increasing the number of parallelies to find the tipping point where it slows down, and use that as a basis to find where the loop or code efficiency slows down. In addition, different hardware can be used to test whether there is an effect on the parallel count.

Comment: @jiayao, Thanks, I'm still looking for possible bottlenecks, increasing and decreasing the number of threads

Comment: @Enigmativity, Thanks for the observation... as I'm focused on looking for execution speed, I overlooked it.

Comment: @AlexiTomala - What type is `request`? Calling `.ToList()` on it is a performance red-flag to me.

Comment: Are there any new discoveries and developments?

Comment: Hi @jiayao, I am carrying out tests, with an example that gives the multitask type library, change so that it calls the .aspx  `code 
                for (int threadIdx = 0; threadIdx < THREADS_COUNT; threadIdx++)
                {
                    workerThreads[threadIdx] = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ConvertHtmlToPdf));
                    workerThreads[threadIdx].Start(threadIdx);
                }
               
                for (int threadIdx = 0; threadIdx < workerThreads.Length; threadIdx++)
                    workerThreads[threadIdx].Join();`

Comment: Invoke the page from the example console and publish it to the server... Progressively increasing the threads(20) I observe that the CPU is degrading/consuming... reaching 98%. I understand that the threads will be queued.

Comment: I cannot cover the number of records processed per hour.

Comment: @AlexiTomala - Please answer my question above.

Comment: Hi @Enigmatividad, I am telling you that I was doing .ToList(), but with the example mentioned above it was no longer necessary to use a list, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @AlexiTomala - You're asking about a performance issue in your current code and the `.ToList()` would add a massive one. Do you understand why?

Comment: @Enigmativity, can you please explain me why?

Comment: @AlexiTomala - Because `.ToList()` fully produces the list. When you then do `.Skip(i * batchSize).Take(batchSize)` you are throwing away all but the current batch. I don't know what type `request` is (hence why I asked) so I don't know how costly `.ToList()` is, but I do know it's allocating at least the entire set of data just before you throw most of it away.

Comment: @AlexiTomala He's right. `Tolist()` can make a big difference when faced with large amounts of data, especially if your cycle is similar to a stress test. I think you could write the code in another way.